# Browserify + Grunt + Remapify: Cannot Find Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify

I've read all the docs and several [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23599580/723007) here, but I can't seem to get Remapify configured properly in my Grunt-Browserify config.

Here are two few variations I've tried, both resulting in the error "Cannot find module..."

```
browserify: {

  options: {
    preBundleCB: function (b) {
      b.plugin(remapify, [{
        cwd: './dev/js/modules',
        src: './**/*.js',
        expose: 'modules'
      }]);
    }
  }
}


browserify: {

  options: {
    preBundleCB: function (b) {
      b.plugin(remapify, [{
        cwd: __dirname,
        src: '.dev/js/modules/**/*.js',
        expose: 'modules'
      }]);
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using it correctly? I don't see any `preBundleCB ` usage in the docs...Maybe it has something to do with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you

```
{
   cwd: './dev/js/modules',
   src: '**/*.js',
   expose: 'modules'
}
```

if expose is an empty string you'll have the same result, very usefull